# ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 distribution upgrade pauses "configuring lightdm" ... "Default display manager:" gdm, lightdm

Tags: 12.04, unity, 14.04, upgrade, gdm

Apologies if I overlooked this in the docs somewhere.  Let me document something just incase it was missed.

My upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 pauses on a package configuration.  The first time I did this I found it to be `stuck` on a screen saying `<Ok>` to continue.  It seemed unresponsive as I was unable to choose "Ok" with the tab or by way of the mouse and unable to proceed.  I hacked around that the first time by guessing and killing that process.  This time, I came to my senses and finally figure out that I could hit tab 3 or 4 times to select "`<Ok>`" then press Enter (I did not screen shot that screen).  So, this should be documented somehow, I would be concerned for anyone upgrading.

So, if you unable to select "`<Ok>`" .. tab repeatedly until it gets selected then press enter.

Now I'm faced with a choice below but I don't know what the implications are.  I have `gdm` installed but I will go with unity.  I don't see a link between Unity and lightdm.

What are the implications of choosing either?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LightDM and GDM are [Display Managers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/display_manager).  If you choose one over the other, the login screen you get differs. That's about it from an end-user perspective.  You can always choose the Display Manager by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm # or gdm
```

You will be presented with a dialogue like the one you have been shown now, and you can select which ever one you want.